# Vue 3 innerHTML attr renders nothing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I have the following Vue 3 component.

```
import { defineComponent, onMounted, ref, Ref, h } from "vue"

export default defineComponent({
    setup(props, context) {
        const divRef = ref() as Ref<HTMLElement>

        return () => {
            return h("div", { ref: divRef }, { innerHTML: "&times;" })
        }
    }
})
```

I want to have the HTML entity `&times;` as it's `innerHTML`. However, the `innerHTML` is always empty for some reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`innerHTML` should be part of the 2nd argument (not 3rd).

```js
export default defineComponent({
    setup(props, context) {
        const divRef = ref() as Ref<HTMLElement>

        return () => h("div", { ref: divRef, innerHTML: "&times;" })
    }
})
```